# Removing Capitalized Strings from Input File in Python3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am importing a text document to list, then removing any item that starts with a capital letter. I can run the code, but I get nothing in the output file.

Relevant Code:

```
def filtercaps(infilename,outfilename):

    import csv
    list_of_words=[]
    list=[]
    a=0    
    with open(infilename, newline='') as inputfile:
            for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
                list.append(row)
    for i in range(len(list)):
        c=str(list[i])
        if c[0] in 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm':
           list_of_words[a]=list[i]
           a=a+1
    f = open(outfilename)
    for i in range(len(list_of_words)):
        f.write(list_of_words[i])
    f.close()

filtercaps("Enable1.txt","Enable2.txt")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it would appear that your file is really a csv file (your are reading the file with `csv.reader`). Assuming that this is the case, the following should work:

```
def filtercaps(infilename,outfilename):

  import csv
  list_of_words=[]
  list=[]
  with open(infilename) as inputfile:
      for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
          list.append(row)
      for l in list:
          if len(l) == 0:
              continue
          first_entry = l[0]
          first_letter = first_entry[0][0]
          if first_letter in 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm':
              list_of_words.append(l)
  f = open(outfilename, "w")
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  for l in list_of_words:
      writer.writerow(l)
  f.close()

filtercaps("Enable1.txt","Enable2.txt")
```

There are other things that one could do to make the script more idiomatic python.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Now all I need to do is group them into anagrams...